# If a function is Lebesgue measureable, does this imply Lebesgue integrability?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Say we take the measure of a countable set, we obtain that $\mu=0$. Now if this is the case, does this automatically imply that it is Lebesgue integrable as well?

The reason I bring up the set is because that set is used to build the characteristic function, which gives us $1$ for elements in the set, but $0$ for elements not in the set. If this set has measure $0$ (or better yet is measurable), then I want to say that if we take the characteristic function, it must be Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: If the function can take positive and negative values, then the definition of the integral might not work if the integrals of the positive and negative parts are both infinite. If the function is always non-negative (or non-positive) and we are happy with an integral being infinity ($\pm\infty$ according to the case) then yes, the definition of the integral always associates a number.

Comment: Sets are never Lebesgue integrable, but certain functions are.

Comment: @zhw. I am working with the Lebesque integral of a simple function (characteristic function). I know that the lebesque measure is zero because it is countable.

Comment: @Alamos Yes, I am working with something that only attains positive values.

Comment: @Frumpy: this is a small detail, but Lebesgue, not Lebesque.

Comment: @ClementC. Sorry my professor uses lebesque.

Comment: He's either wrong or writes very badly, I reckon.

Comment: I will fix that, but that does not help me with my question :)

Comment: I don't understand the questions. The first sentence is about sets, but the second asks about functions. (Sets are not objects described as "integrable.")

Comment: The reason I bring up the set is because that set is used to build the characteristic function, which gives us 1 for elements in the set, but 0 for elements not in the set. If this set has measure 0 (or better yet is measurable), then I want to say that if we take the characteristic function, it must be lebesque integrable.

Comment: If understand your question, the answer is yes. The characteristic is integrable over a set iff the set is measurable.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Yes, this is exactly what I am asking. Now what makes this true?

Comment: @Frumpy If a set is measurable, then, the integral of its characteristic function is exactly the measure of the set (this follows from the definition of integral). Therefore, the characteristic function is integrable. Conversely, if the characteristic function of a set is integrable, then, the measure of the set is this integral, and the set is measurable.

Comment: @ViníciusNovelli I read a theorem saying that a simple function is Lebesgue integrable if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|\mathcal{X}_{\mathbb{A}} < \infty$. Since we are working with a countable set and a characteristic function of that set, don't we simply need to show that $\mu(\mathbb{A}) < \infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Say you want yo integrate your characteristic function of a measurable set $A$ with $\mu(A)=0$ contained in a measurable space $X$. By the definition of the Lebesgue integral:

$$
\int_X \chi_A(x)\, dx = 1\cdot \mu (A)+ 0\cdot \mu(X\backslash A)=1\cdot 0 + 0 = 0.
$$

Also, your set need not be countable, but is only required to have measure zero. Think of the Cantor set, for example, which is uncountable and has measure zero.

Answer (score 0):

A function, $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if for all $r\in \mathbb R$, $f^{-1}((-\infty, r]) = \{ x\in X \ |\ f(x)\leq r\}$ is a measurable set. From this, you should be able to conclude that $\chi_A$ is measurable for all measurable $A$.

Integrability is harder, but the idea is that a function is integrable if it is measurable and has a finite integral over any set (so no cancelling positive bits with negative bits). Your question comes down to "is the measure of a countable set finite?" Well, you can rewrite a countable set as $\cup_{i\in\mathbb N} \{a_i\}$, and from there you can write its measure as $\sum_i \mu(\{a_i\}).$ So, what is the measure of a singleton, and what do you get if you sum that a countable number of times?